# Flutter: Get text inside a TextFormField from from a DropDownMenu and DatePicker

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to get some text inside a TextFormField after selecting some values from a DropDownMenu and DatePicker?

In my app i have TextFormField where i want to input some text over the keyboard or instead  selecting from a DropDownMenu and DatePicker.

After the text is insert into the TextFormField over a press of a button the value will be displayed on the Screen.

I am able after selecting from the DroDownMenu and Datepicker and pressing the button to display it on the scree.

But i want that the selected DropDownMenu and Datepicker values goes first inside the TextFormField and after pressing the button it will be displayed on the screen.

Tahnks in advance for some help.

Follows the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() async {
  Get.put(SpringTesterController());
  runApp(const GetMaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GetBuilder<SpringTesterController>(
            init: SpringTesterController(),
            builder: (gtxs1) {
              return const MyHomePage();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<SpringTesterController>(
        init: SpringTesterController(),
        builder: (gtxs1) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Name:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    gtxs1.displayedValue,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color(0xFFEF6C00),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.calendar_month_outlined,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await gtxs1.selectDate(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  DropdownButton(
                    value: gtxs1.selectedValue,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      gtxs1.onSelectedDropdown(value.toString());
                    },
                    items: const [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '1',
                        child: Text('1'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '2',
                        child: Text('2'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '3',
                        child: Text('3'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '4',
                        child: Text('4'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        onChanged: gtxs1.onTextFieldChanged,
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.save,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        gtxs1.setName();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}


class SpringTesterController extends GetxController {
  static SpringTesterController get to => Get.find();
  String? selectedValue;
  String enteredValue = '';
  String displayedValue = '';
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  void onSelectedDropdown(String newValue) {
    selectedValue = newValue;
    update();
  }

  void onTextFieldChanged(String newValue) {
    enteredValue = newValue;
    update();
  }

  void setName() {
    if (enteredValue.isNotEmpty) {
      displayedValue = enteredValue;
    } else {
      if (selectedValue != null) {
        displayedValue = '${selectedValue!} $_selectedDate';
      } else {
        displayedValue = _selectedDate.toString();
      }
    }
    update();
  }

  Future<void> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2015),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      _selectedDate = picked;
    }
    update();
  }
}
```

Modified code that accomplished.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  Get.put(SpringTesterController());
  runApp(const GetMaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GetBuilder<SpringTesterController>(
            init: SpringTesterController(),
            builder: (gtxs1) {
              return const MyHomePage();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<SpringTesterController>(
        init: SpringTesterController(),
        builder: (gtxs1) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'JSON File Name2:  ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    gtxs1.displayedValue,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color(0xFFEF6C00),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.calendar_month_outlined,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await gtxs1._selectDate(context).then((selectedDate) {
                        textController.text = selectedDate.toString();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  DropdownButton(
                    value: gtxs1.selectedValue,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      gtxs1.onSelectedDropdown(value.toString());
                      textController.text = value.toString();
                    },
                    items: const [
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '1',
                        child: Text('1'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '2',
                        child: Text('2'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '3',
                        child: Text('3'),
                      ),
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: '4',
                        child: Text('4'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 250,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter some text';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onChanged: gtxs1.onTextFieldChanged,
                        controller: textController,
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.save,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        gtxs1.setName();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}


class SpringTesterController extends GetxController {
  static SpringTesterController get to => Get.find();
  String? selectedValue;
  String enteredValue = '';
  String displayedValue = '';
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  void onSelectedDropdown(String newValue) {
    selectedValue = newValue;
    update();
  }

  void onTextFieldChanged(String newValue) {
    enteredValue = newValue;
    update();
  }

  void setName() {
    if (enteredValue.isNotEmpty) {
      displayedValue = enteredValue;
    } else {
      if (selectedValue != null) {
        displayedValue = '${selectedValue!} $_selectedDate';
      } else {
        displayedValue = _selectedDate.toString();
      }
    }
    update();
  }

  Future<DateTime> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      _selectedDate = picked;
    }
    update();
    return _selectedDate;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define controller inside your `MyHomePageState` class like below:

`TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();`

Assign controller in your `TextFormField` like below:

```
                       TextFormField(
                        onChanged: gtxs1.onTextFieldChanged,
                        controller: textController,
                      ),
```

Assign text to controller when you tap on  `DropdownMenu` you want like below:

`textController.text = 'your data from Dropdown/DatePicker'`;

For more information please refer Official documentation of [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Tip and help. I could accomplished what i needed. I put updated code in my question.